# Java - run Python script and monitor continuous output

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, processbuilder, spi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to receive the UID of some RFID cards from a RC522 reader. The python script I'm running is here: https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python

For various reasons I won't go into, I have to process these IDs in Java.

It seems the most viable solution is to run the python script and read in the result into Java. The problem is, the Python code gives **continuous** output, *i.e.* it will print the ID of the card into the console window as and when a card is tapped onto the reader, and will only terminate on a user's command.

I'm currently using a ProcessBuilder to execute the script, however it seems like it's more suited to run the program and read in the immediate result back to Java (which of course is *null* if I haven't tapped a card onto the reader). I've tried executing the code in a while(true) loop to continuously start the process - but this doesn't work:

```
    import java.io.*;

public class PythonCaller {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up the command and parameter
        String pythonScriptPath = "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/Read.py";
        String[] cmd = new String[3];
        cmd[0] = "sudo";
        cmd[1] = "python"; // check version of installed python: python -V
        cmd[2] = pythonScriptPath;

        // create runtime to execute external command
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        // retrieve output from python script
        pb.redirectError();

        while(true){
            Process p = pb.start();
            System.out.println("Process Started...");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
            System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
            }
        }
}
```

The output on the console window is blank - no exceptions thrown or println's.

Any help would be massively appreciated!!

Thanks

**EDIT - I've surrounded my code in a try/catch to see if there's anything at all being thrown, and it doesn't seem to be the case**

Answer (score 1):

I use the following programs to try to reproduce the problem

**PythonCaller.java**

```
import java.io.*;    
public class PythonCaller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up the command and parameter
        String pythonScriptPath = "/home/pi/test.py";
        String[] cmd = { "python", pythonScriptPath };

        // create runtime to execute external command
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        // retrieve output from python script       
        pb.redirectError();

        while(true){
            Process p = pb.start();
            System.out.println("Process Started...");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
            System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
        }
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```
uid =(123,456,789,999)
print "Card read UID: "+str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3])
```

1. The method `pb.redirectError()` doesn't modify anything.  It returns a value, your codes does nothing with it.  (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError%28%29).  What you want is probably `redirectErrorStream(boolean redirectErrorStream)`
2. The second line of the python test program is taken directly from "Read.py" (line 44).  It causes an error with the java `intValue()` method.  If I replace it with `String ret = in.readLine();`, the program seems to work.
3. Since the `Process p = pb.start();` is inside the loop, the python subprogram is called repeatedly.

The next step should be to try running the python program manually in a console, see what it does.

(n.b. I had to remove "sudo" and change paths to be able to test on my system, you should have no problems replacing things for your setup).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help so far!
I've replicated your solution, and it works perfectly for test.py - replacing it with the actual program still doesn't show anything other than "Process Started..." on the console.....

It's odd because running Read.py from command line itself produces the desired output without issue......

Comment: Done a hacky workaround but I'm upvoting your answer because that's still given me some very useful tips, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get around it by editing my Python script - it returns null if there's no card on the reader, and the UID if there is.

I'll probably use observer pattern or similar on the Java end to detect when there's a card. Very resource intensive but it'll have to do for now!